# why we should use gray scale for image processing

Tags: image-processing

I think this can be a stupid question but after read a lot and search a lot about image processing every example I see about image processing uses gray scale to work

I understood that gray scale images use just one channel of color, that normally is necessary just 8 bit to be represented, etc... but, why use gray scale when we have a color image? What are the advantages of a gray scale? I could imagine that is because we have less bits to treat but even today with faster computers this is necessary?

I am not sure if I was clear about my doubt, I hope someone can answer me

thank you very much

Comment: Even if you don't grayscale the image, all image processing requires some form of collapsing data since even with modern computers, processing raw images is nigh impossible. Even our brains, which one could say are computers built mainly for such tasks, compress and ignore lots of visual input to make sight possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As [explained by John Zhang](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Vision/If-you-had-to-choose-would-you-rather-go-without-luminance-or-chrominance/answer/John-Zhang):

> luminance is by far more important in distinguishing visual features

John also gives an excellent suggestion to illustrate this property: take a given image and separate the luminance plane from the chrominance planes.

To do so you can use ImageMagick [separate](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#separate) operator that *extracts the current contents of each channel as a gray-scale image*:

```
convert myimage.gif -colorspace YCbCr -separate sep_YCbCr_%d.gif
```

Here's what it gives on a sample image (top-left: original color image, top-right: luminance plane, bottom row: chrominance planes):

[image]

Comment: Okay, on revisiting your answer (and mine), I realize I really want a copy of Lisa Ekdal sings Salvadore Poe. Nearly ten years have passed, and I'm just now listening to samples online. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUXk4YQLBZo

Answer (score 27):

To elaborate a bit on deltheil's answer:

1. Signal to noise. For many applications of image processing, color information doesn't help us identify important edges or other features. There are exceptions. If there is an edge (a step change in pixel value) in hue that is hard to detect in a grayscale image, or if we need to identify objects of known hue (orange fruit in front of green leaves), then color information could be useful. If we don't need color, then we can consider it noise. At first it's a bit counterintuitive to "think" in grayscale, but you get used to it.
2. Complexity of the code. If you want to find edges based on luminance AND chrominance, you've got more work ahead of you. That additional work (and additional debugging, additional pain in supporting the software, etc.) is hard to justify if the additional color information isn't helpful for applications of interest.
3. For learning image processing, it's better to understand grayscale processing first and understand how it applies to multichannel processing rather than starting with full color imaging and missing all the important insights that can (and should) be learned from single channel processing.
4. Difficulty of visualization. In grayscale images, the watershed algorithm is fairly easy to conceptualize because we can think of the two spatial dimensions and one brightness dimension as a 3D image with hills, valleys, catchment basins, ridges, etc. "Peak brightness" is just a mountain peak in our 3D visualization of the grayscale image. There are a number of algorithms for which an intuitive "physical" interpretation helps us think through a problem. In RGB, HSI, Lab, and other color spaces this sort of visualization is much harder since there are additional dimensions that the standard human brain can't visualize easily. Sure, we can think of "peak redness," but what does that mountain peak look like in an (x,y,h,s,i) space? Ouch. One workaround is to think of each color variable as an intensity image, but that leads us right back to grayscale image processing.
5. Color is complex. Humans perceive color and identify color with deceptive ease. If you get into the business of attempting to distinguish colors from one another, then you'll either want to (a) follow tradition and control the lighting, camera color calibration, and other factors to ensure the best results, or (b) settle down for a career-long journey into a topic that gets deeper the more you look at it, or (c) wish you could be back working with grayscale because at least then the problems seem solvable.
6. Speed. With modern computers, and with parallel programming, it's possible to perform simple pixel-by-pixel processing of a megapixel image in milliseconds. Facial recognition, OCR, content-aware resizing, mean shift segmentation, and other tasks can take much longer than that. Whatever processing time is required to manipulate the image or squeeze some useful data from it, most customers/users want it to go faster. If we make the hand-wavy assumption that processing a three-channel color image takes three times as long as processing a grayscale image--or maybe four times as long, since we may create a separate luminance channel--then that's not a big deal if we're processing video images on the fly and each frame can be processed in less than 1/30th or 1/25th of a second. But if we're analyzing thousands of images from a database, it's great if we can save ourselves processing time by resizing images, analyzing only portions of images, and/or eliminating color channels we don't need. Cutting processing time by a factor of three to four can mean the difference between running an 8-hour overnight test that ends before you get back to work, and having your computer's processors pegged for 24 hours straight.

Of all these, I'll emphasize the first two: make the image simpler, and reduce the amount of code you have to write.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the implication that gray scale images are always better than color images; it depends on the technique and the overall goal of the processing.  For example, if you wanted to count the bananas in an image of a fruit bowl image, then it's much easier to segment when you have a colored image!

Many images have to be in grayscale because of the measuring device used to obtain them.  Think of an electron microscope.  It's measuring the strength of an electron beam at various space points.  An AFM is measuring the amount of resonance vibrations at various points topologically on a sample.  In both cases, these tools are returning a singular value- an intensity, so they implicitly are creating a gray-scale image.

For image processing techniques based on brightness, they often can be applied sufficiently to the overall brightness (grayscale); however, there are many many instances where having a colored image is an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Binary might be too simple and it could not represent the picture character.
Color might be too much and affect the processing speed.

Thus, grayscale is chosen, which is in the mid of the two ends.

Answer (score 1):

First of starting image processing whether on gray scale or color images, it is better to focus on the applications which we are applying. Unless and otherwise, if we choose one of them randomly, it will create accuracy problem in our result. For example, if I want to process image of waste bin, I prefer to choose gray scale rather than color. Because in the bin image I want only to detect the shape of bin image using optimized edge detection. I could not bother about the color of image but I want to see rectangular shape of the bin image correctly.